# Extract audio aac from mp4

Tags: mp4, aac, mp4box

Is there a command line tool for Windows to extract audio aac from mp4 ?

Comment: How to change compatible brand with mp4box?  -brand doesn't work!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

FFmpeg can do it. [Here](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/19-ffmpeg-commands-for-all-needs) is a list of commands that might come useful for you.
Go [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-a-Flash-Video-File-%28.flv%29-to-MP4-with-FFMpeg) for instructions.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -c copy -map 0:a:0 Output.aac
```

- `-i`: input file
- `-c copy`: copies the bitstreams without re-encoding
- `-map 0:a:0`: selects track from: 1st input file -> audio tracks -> first track (1st audio track from 1st input file)

Note that it would work similarly with `avconv`, which is a fork of `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Only linking to a solution is bad practice. At least give some examples.

Comment: If there's only one audio stream inside the MP4, the -map argument is not necessary, ie. writing this is enough: 
`ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -c copy Output.aac`

Comment: Here is how to create in batch mode. First create a sub-folder "out" where your mp4 files are. Then, "open command window" to the mp4 folder and paste the following

for %f in ("*.mp4") do C:\yourpath\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg -i "%f" -c copy -map 0:a:0 out/"%~nf.aac"

Comment: How do you do this when you want to extract ALL audio tracks?

Answer (score 13):

mp4box can also do this.

To demux/extract aac from mp4 (assuming audio is the 2nd track):

```
mp4box -raw 2 video.mp4
```

This will automatically create output file "video_track2.aac"

(Use `mp4box -info video.mp4` to get a list of the tracks in the MP4 file.)

If you wanted control over the output filename, you would do

```
mp4box -raw 2 video.mp4 -out audio.aac
```

If you wanted to remux back into mp4 container (i.e. for iTunes) you could do:

```
mp4box -single 2 video.mp4 -out audio.m4a
```

You could then put this in a batch script to operate over all the files in a directory:

```
for %%f in ("*.mp4") do (

mp4box -single 2 "%%f" -out "%%~nf.m4a"

)
```

(batch script inspired by [videohelp](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/345738-MP4Box-command-to-batch-MUX-MP4s?p=2158662&viewfull=1#post2158662) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215501/batch-remove-file-extension))

Download links:

- https://github.com/gpac/gpac/releases
- http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/downloads/gpac-nightly-builds/

Comment: +1 Thank you, the -single command is exactly what I was looking for (it adds MP4 info to -raw)

Answer (score 7):

Here’s the actual commands to use since all the provided links don’t actually give them, and anyway: links rot and die so should always be replaced with actual answers on stackexchange.

```
avconv -i input.mp4 -vn -c:a copy output.m4a
```

Comment: Worked great (with parent project "ffmpeg.exe" instead of "avconv.exe") and fixed .aac output problem of inaccurate timecode. Turns out m4a is a proper container format.

Comment: I'm getting "Output file #0 does not contain any stream"

Answer (score 0):

I first just use mkvtoolnix to convert the MP4 to MKV and use mkvextract gui to extract the needed track. Lot less complicated and full GUI. Absolutely zero change in any component whatsoever.

Comment: If it’s less complicated, can you please describe how to do what the OP wants to do with these tools?  Also, note that the question asked for a command line tool.

Comment: Actually mkvtoolnix is a graphical front end for the command line mkvmerge.exe I believe you can find the command line switches and command formatting information on line too. The GUI also has the option of creating batch files for working on multiple files.